# Luxon DateTime.utc() returns different times on different devices

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset, luxon

I've been reading for days about timezones and offsets but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a quiz application in which the client has 5 minutes to solve a quiz. When the client sends a request to start the quiz, the server records the `start_time` of the quiz as that instant, and the `end_time` as `start_time + 5min`.

This `end_time` is sent to the browser, which then shows a countdown timer to the client by calculating the difference between the browser's `current_time` and the `end_time`.
The problem is that the browser's `current_time` is different on different devices, even if they are in the same timezone. If a device is 2 minutes ahead of the standard time of its timezone, then its quiz ends 2 minutes earlier than every other device.

I tried using UTC time universally, on the server as well as the client, however, at the same exact instant, `luxon.DateTime.utc()` returns different a different time on each device. My phone's time is 2 minutes ahead of my laptop's time, and so `DateTime.utc()` returns, on my phone, a time that is 2 minutes ahead of that on my laptop. I don't want the device's time converted to UTC, I want an absolute time frame of reference that doesn't vary with device time.

Comment: Hi.  This isn't any issue with time zones or Luxon, but simply that you've discovered that system clocks of multiple devices are not guaranteed to be synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find the answer to how the method I mentioned above can be implemented, but I found another way to implement the timer.

Instead of the server sending the `end_time` to the browser, the server sends the `remaining_time` which is `end_time-server_current_time`. The client receives this `remaining_time` and sets the countdown for `client_current_time+remaining_time`.

Comment: This approach works well.  Since you are calculating time remaining on the server, you can ensure the server's clock is synchronized with NTP (most are) and don't have to consider the client's clock.  It will also survive page refreshes, or the client using multiple devices/browsers.  However, if you *didn't* need to survive that, you could simply call `setTimeout` and the start/current/end date-times would all be irrelavent.